# How to solve the live server problem in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

the live srever dosn't open the page in browser.
and i tried to open this http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html in browser, it show me the code that i have but when I make some changes the page content dosn't refreash automatically I musst to refreash the page to show the changes the I made.

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

1)Re-install the Liveserver extension and restart Your VSCode.

Also You can..

2)Set the browser for Live Server in `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`
Scroll all the way to the bottom of the file, add a comma after the last setting, then paste in `"liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"` or `"firefox"` or another :) save the settings.json file and try to run Live Server again.

3. If You have still this problem  check out this links =>
   https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/452
   and
   https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/65
4. When all fails, write to the support of Visual Studio Code and describe the problem exactly. In Vscode click `View` then `Command Pallette` then type `Report Issue`.

I hope it helps :-) Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the browser in launch.json to you favorite web browser

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "terminal.integrated.copyOnSelection": true,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
        /** Here on the line below you change the name chrome to your favorite we browser*/
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.AdvanceCustomBrowserCmdLine": "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true
}
```